# What's the preferred method on logstash to use instead of grep?

Tags: grep, logstash

grep plugin is using the `milestone` method to declare the version of the plugin this method is deprecated in favor of declaring the version inside the gemspec. `{:level=>:warn}`

grep plugin doesn't have a version. This plugin isn't well supported by the community and likely has no maintainer. `{:level=>:warn}`

I get this warning when I used grep on `logstash`. What should I use in its place?

Answer (score 1):

To remove events, use conditionals and drop{}:

```
if [field] == "value" {
    drop{}
}
```

To add fields or tags, you can use almost any filter, but I like mutate{}:

```
mutate {
    add_field => { "name" => "value" }
    add_tag => [ "value" ]
}
```